# Set width of the fixed block relative to parent div (container)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `container`, and in it I have a `position:fixed` block. I need this block's width to be 40% of the size of the container.
The problem is, when you apply `position:fixed` to a block, width is no longer relative to the parent, it's relative to the screen size.

I can't fix this with `percent` or `px`, cause it will brake the layout on some devices.

*I am using Twitter-Bootstrap's container class*

Comment: Do you want block to be same width as `parent` div?

Comment: @NenadVracar `I need this block's width to be 40% of the size of the container.`

Comment: @NenadVracar if I did, i would just used `width:inherit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `width: inherit;` to inherit the width of the parent div.

In this example i've created a container that has a fixed position and inherits the width of its parent. Within this fixed container there's another div that has a 40% width of the fixed container.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.container-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.container-fixed-inner {
  width: 40%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fixed">
    <div class="container-fixed-inner">
      <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```